# How to design different collection cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, rx-cocoa

i've a `collectionView` with different `collectionCell` and i want to set a scale/height/size depending of the cell. How can i do it ?

Here is the image of my different cell : a `title cell`, and 2 different `cell image`. One is width of the view / 3 and the other is / 2. I can't do it with auto layout constraint in the story board so i need to do in the code. I'm trying to use the collectionViewLayout.

[image: CollectionView]

Comment: how many collectionviewcell you require in your collectionview  ?

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya Hello, i've 6 different cell. But only 3 different design (title, image scale view / 3 and image scale view / 2. Like the storyboard image

Comment: then put condition in collectionviewcelllayout delagates method and give frame it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

implement

`class MyViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource , UICollectionViewDelegate , UICollectionViewFlowLayout`

in `ViewDidLoad`

```
collectionView.delegate = self;
collectionView.datasource = self;
```

add delegate of flow layout

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    if indexPath.row == 0 || indexPath.row == 1 || indexPath.row == 2{
      return CGSize(self.view.frame.size.width / 3, 100)
     }

  else{
      return CGSize(self.view.frame.size.width / 2, 100)
    }
//  return the size you what
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement you can do like this way

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
   if (indexPath.row >= 0 && indexPath.row < 3) {
        return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width / 3.15, height: 150)
        // here give size for 3 collectionviewcell in one row . i use 3.5 beacause of i put spacing 10 pix left and right side of collectionview.
   }
   else if (indexPath.row >=3 && indexPath.row < 5){
       return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width / 2.20, height: 150)
        // here give size for 2 collectionviewcell in one row.
   }else{
      return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width / 3.15, height: 150)
   }

}
```

**Output :**

[image: as they requirement 6 cell in collectionview]

Comment: You should create a more general solution rather than hard coding the numbers to match the exact values.

Comment: @Rikh then tell me what is general solution for this question.

Comment: Good job at least you are trying to help.